# Django, update profile, check if email is unique(exclude logged in user's email)

Tags: python, django, validation, email

In an **update profile** page, there are 3 fields.

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email Address

By the method below, I'm trying to see if the email address entered in the field is unique(not used by other members). But when the email address entered(placeholder) is the current email address of the logged in user, I'm still getting an error that **This email is already in use. Try another one**.

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exclude(email=email):
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.'
                                    'Please supply a different email address.')
    return email
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to update users' email. My problem was because I was trying to use the same form to update and to create an user. If you have a form that checks if the email is used you cannot use it to update user because it will fails like it's happening now. When it is an update I recommend you to use another form (updateUserForm) and then the def clean_email  function just have to check that the new email is not used for other users, something like

```
if not User.objects.filter(email=email):
      #Then there is no other users with the new email
      #Do whatever you have to do, return true or update user
else:
     raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.'
                                    'Please supply a different email address.')
```

**EDIT** (update user info):

To change the email of some user you have to follow 3 steps. Load the user, change the attributes you want and then save:

```
existing_user = User.objects.get(id=1)  #You have to change this for your query or user    
existing_user.email = 'new@email.com'    
existing_user.save()
```

*Obviously nobody has to be using 'new@email.com'*

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I just got back to this issue. I do have a separate form(updateProfile). But still with `def clean_email` it finds the currents user's email address in the database so still saying that `email already in use`. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: To update profile the function is different, to change the email of an existing account you have to load the user, change the email and save the update, check my edition in this post.

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
class UserCreationEmailForm(UserCreationForm):

email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

def clean_email(self):
        # Check that email is not duplicate
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        users = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exclude(username__iexact=username)
        if users:
            raise forms.ValidationError('A user with that email already exists.')
        return email.lower()
```